# Is there a command-line way to get information about a gradle task?

Tags: gradle

Is there some kind of command like `gradlew help <task>` that gives documentation about what exactly goes on in a particular task?

Comment: What kind of information are you looking for specifically? A task can describe its purpose using the `description` property. This description is shown when you run `gradle tasks`.

Comment: @BenjaminMuschko Yeah I see those descriptions, but it looks like each of those tasks have dependencies on tasks (subtasks?) that aren't really listed in the `gradle tasks` list. For example, when I run the build task using the android plugin, I see this output: https://gist.github.com/matthewmichihara/6846646. Is there a way to get information about what's going on in each of those steps?

Comment: Run `gradle tasks --all` for that.

Comment: @BenjaminMuschko Ah ok that gives me the full list, but now I want to know what is going on in each of those subtask steps. Maybe it's not possible and I just need to read the code?

Comment: I'd say have a look at the documentation of the plugin that exposes the tasks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is

```
gradle help --task <taskname>
```

for exactly this now.

Answer (score 32):

```
gradlew -dry-run <task>
```

will show what will be executed for the command.  A shortcut version is:

```
gradlew -m <task>
```

Also

```
gradlew tasks
```

will show a list of *all* tasks and their dependencies.

Comment: That's kind of helpful, but doesn't really give me any documentation about what each individual task is doing.

Comment: The command line flag `-t` does not exist anymore. It was replaced by the `tasks` task.

Comment: Oops.  Yes, I'm currently using a *very* old version of Gradle, trying to get upgraded but not there yet.